# Powershell how to get the result code from REST

Tags: powershell, rest

I'm sending a POST request with ID/password and I need to get back a respond token, how can I get it and save it for later use in the script?

```
$loginUrl = "https://some-ip"

$params = @{
 "username"="$username"
 "password"="$password"
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $loginUrl -Method POST -Body ($params|ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your input:

```
$url = "https://some-ip"

$params = @{
 "username" = $username
 "password" = $password
} | ConvertTo-Json

$apiReturn = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $params -ContentType "application/json"
```

`$apiReturn` can then be used as response.

Furthermore, you can use the `SessionVariable` parameter of `Invoke-RestMethod`.

```
$apiReturn = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $params -ContentType "application/json" -SessionVariable sessionToken
$sessionToken.Headers.Add('Authorization', $apiReturn)
$sessionToken.Headers.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

In this scenario, you add the response token to 'Authorization' and forward the whole token to your subsequent API calls. Like this you only need to add `$sessionToken` and `Content-Type` for example is already provided.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -WebSession $sessionToken
```

You can add more parameters to your Header in case it is required.